# How to find out if variable value in database json column Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, codeigniter

Im using Codeigniter. Im trying to get some value in database like;

```
$this->db->where('json_value','test1');
```

the problem is 'json_value' column is like = `[{"name":"test1","value":"test1"},{"name":"test2","value":"test2"}]`

how can I get 'test1' if 'json_value' has?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LIKE in your query

```
$this->db->like('json_value', 'test1', 'both');
```

For more information read the [CI3 documentation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-similar-data).